# Automate web login for Wi-Fi hotspots

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, auto-login

Many Wi-Fi hotspots these days have a "web login", especially free ones. You know, the ones that redirect any HTTP request to their login form. Windows usually displays the "Additional login information may be required" notification for these.

Is there a way that I can automate the process of such logins, ie. save my username and password (for a given hotspot)? Ideally, I want this to happen without even opening my usual browser, although if the process itself automatically opens and closes an Internet Explorer window to perform the login that might be OK.

Comment: try using lastpass, it automatically logs you in when the webpage is opened

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm after. I don't want to open a browser for this at all.

Comment: It's very frustrating that this question has been closed.  I do not think this qualifies as a "shopping question".  He's not asking for help on which laptop to buy (which requires an incredible amount of detail to answer usefully), he's asking for *one* program or technique that accomplishes this.  Do any exist?  There's no risk here of any of the problems described in the shopping question blog post.  SE is the greatest thing since sliced bread, but this particular category of off-topic-ness is broken.

Comment: @JessRiedel Shopping recommendation doesn't mean hardware, it can mean software too. The reason for this is because we want questions and answers to be valid for a long time. While a software recommendation can be helpful, it might not be years from now when the software isn't around or doesn't offer the desired functionality any more. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com might be a better place to post this, though. Our [help center](http://superuser.com/help) is a good place to read up on on-topic stuff.

Comment: First, I wasn't making a distinction between hardware and software. I was making a distinction between a complex, user-specific, non-generalizable problem and a simple, broadly applicable one. Second, there are innumerable questions on this website with 1 or 2 year useful lifetime, so that criterion so that does not select against this question. Third, I have read the on topic material. I simply do not think it is being applied correctly here.

Comment: "Is there a program out there?"  Try on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, that has already been suggested. Erring on the side of closure so the question can be shuttled off to a beta SE is not a good solution. I'd rather have the rules applied sensibly here.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect better what it should say to avoid the closure. However, IMO, it shouldn't have been closed int he first place and is a valid question for SU.  I've also nominated for reopening.

Comment: First thing came to my mind was Keepass but then I read your comment above and realized that you do not want to open a browser window at all. I think you should clarify this in your question.

Comment: Fair point - clarified. I don't want to open my usual browser, because it restores all existing tabs and *all* of them get redirected to the login page. Then I have to either log in in every tab or click back in most of them - and depending on the Wifi provider sometimes the back button is broken, too. But if the login process opened a different browser just to log in that would be OK.

Comment: @EM I had a similar problem. I was "OK" with logging on to their network through a WebUI, but their WebUI made my eyes bleed. So I made a [quick and dirty script to automate login process.](https://bitbucket.org/thrustmaster/tikona-login). Essentially, whatever your browser does, you should be able to imitate it. Maintain a session (a cookie jar?), fire the exact same HTTP requests, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

I would create a curl command which executes on system boot. When the commands executes it will send your authentication details and log you in.

This can be achieved with Google chromes "copy as curl" feature. Copy the get request as a curl command from your web browser after you've clicked the login button into a bash script.

This assume authentication by mac address, however if its by cookie you could save the returned cookie in the appropriate browsers cookie folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Other than scripting as already suggested, there don't appear to be any Windows applications that support this. There are several Android/iOS apps however.

Comment: Can you post links to those Android/iOS apps please.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wefi.wefi&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

@Thrustmaster pointed at his Python script but you could also use PowerShell to do this.

Run the PS script which would use the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet to connect to any known site (in the UK, we usually use bbc.co.uk, mainly because it is easy to type :)

You would then need to parse the returned object checking to make sure it wasn't the expected site.

Then you would need to identify the fields that need filling in. This would be the hard part! Not too bad if you know the layout of the login page or just have a few known pages.

Then fill in the form fields required and submit.

Finally get the script to open your browser normally.

Or maybe it would be a lot easier to keep another browser installed and just use that when on a Wi-Fi network that needed a login!

Answer (score -1):

Mili is my script that helps for auto login hotspot pages!

https://github.com/SadeghHayeri/Mili

​

Mili automatically checks for Mikrotik services and then try login with your login information.

also you can use multi login information like this:

```
    [
        {
            "username": "user1",
            "password": "pass1",
            "share": 5
        },
        {
            "username": "user2",
            "password": "pass2",
            "share": 1
        }
    ]
```